# problem with particles not coliding

Tags: particles, collision, rigidbody

I'm making a animation with balls rolling on a plane. I cant figure out how to get the balls to collide.
Thanks,
sincerely TC

Comment: pls provide blend file because you didn't provide any useful information. thx.

Comment: Are your balls particles or can they be rigid body instead? In the latter case, the simulation will be more accurate

Comment: Please bring up a specific case, with the work you've done so far. Tell us what you want, in your case. It will be even easier for us if you share a file on  https://blend-exchange.com/. If you illustrate your post, folks will be able to judge whether they can help before committing to a download.